# Insert strings at multiple (but limited) matches in another string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text-manipulation

I have this string in Javascript:

```
text = "2222 22:22: John: New York /n last year and: the next year /n 3333 33:33: Jack: Los Angeles!!!"
```

I want it to be the following:

```
newText = "(xSep)2222 22:22:(zSep) John:(zSep) New York /n last year and: the next year /n (xSep)3333 33:33:(zSep) Jack:(zSep) Los Angeles!!!"
```

I've tried many things and only this way could my rest of the code work.
So a "(xSep)" should come **before** *every four numbers* and a "(zSep)" should come **after** *only* the first two ": "

Please help me with this. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I'm confused - where exactly do you want (zsep) to appear?

Comment: after only the first two occurrences of a `": "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your given output and requirement, you can use the following.

```
var res = str.replace(/(\d{4}(?:[^:]*:){2})([^:]*:)/g, '(xSep)$1(zSep)$2(zSep)');
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/229016)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked really the way I wanted it.. could you please explain the way you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use string.replace method with regex as needle.

Comment: I've tried this but I can't get it to replace the four digits with (xSep)theSameFourDigits